# Visual Studio - Rebuild dependencies when code changed

Tags: visual-studio, build

I would like to rebuild all dependencies when I launch the application and that the code changed.
I've already tried a few solutions I found :

1. Tools >> Options >> Project and Solution >> Build and Run >> Check that "On run, when projects are out of date" is set to "Always build" or "Prompt to build". Then, Build >> Configuration Manager >> Check "Build" for all projects I need. But it did not work.
2. I tried deleting the .vs file, restarting Visual Studio, unloading and reloading the project, but it did not work.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.3.6.
If you need any more information, please ask !

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your references are not correct and therefore you might have wrongly concluded that your assemblies are not getting rebuilt when in fact they are. Are you sure that your references are project references and not references where you selected the path and file location for a particular DLL? If you're not sure, delete assembly references to your projects and recreate them as project references by browsing to the project in question.

Also, Visual Studio will rebuild only projects that are in the current solution--you must have compilable projects in order for those projects to be rebuilt.

If the above didn't lead you to the answer, please advise.

Comment: Building manually works, so I guess my dependency is correct.To add a dependency, I did : Right click on my project >> Add >> Reference >> Went to Projects >> Checked my other project

Comment: You say you want to rebuild when launching. How exactly are you launching the program? Also, you say that it works when you build manually—as opposed to what? How are you building when it fails?

Comment: I launch the project by clicking on the green arrow/triangle at the top. When I do that, the projects do not re-build automatically, even if my code changed. However, if I manually go to Build >> Rebuild solution it works. Sorry if it was not clear before

Comment: Please inspect the Output window when you launch your program and let me know if you see anything that might explain why your projects are not getting rebuilt...